# Is scanning BLE devices in Windows 10 under Cordova possible?

Tags: windows, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy

I wrote an app with cordova (8.1.2) to communicate with a BLE (blutooth low energy) device. I got it running on Android, and I managed to build a Windows 10 version too.

But under Windows 10 no device will be found.

If the evothings.ble.startScan function is called, no error callback function is called, but unfortunately the onDeviceFound callback is never called too.

If I try to connect to my device via the Windows 10 Control Center the device is found and I also managed to connect to it.

The answerable question is: Is scanning for BLE devices supported by the evothings cordova plugin under Windows 10? If so, what do I have to do to get it running?

Plugin source: https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble

In the evothings website (https://evothings.com/evothings-studio-2-2-0-released/) there is a broken link to a forum, so I cannot ask this question there.

Comment: No, it does not look possible. The code look sonly in paired/known devices list only. But does not actualy discover devices.

Comment: I dont want to start a discussion here - but can someone give me a workaround starting point? The app cannot know the IDs of the devices. So how can I connect these devices with a cordova html5 app?

Comment: You have to use [BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher) to find devices and [BluetoothLEDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice) to connect.